# Returning data from a single Child record (sorted by date) with Parent data also

Tags: sql, sql-server

As a SQL noob I have a, what I am assuming, basic question about 1 to many children records.

I have an order table and an Order_Status child table.

```
Order table
ID    Order_Number    Status    Order_Date    ect

Order_Status table
StatusTo    StatusFrom    Order_ID    StatusChange_Date
```

The child table can have many enties for the status changing for a single parent order.

How do I pull back the following information as a single record with the child tables's (os) most recent record for that parent(p)? (`p.Order_Number, p.Status, p.Order_Date, os.StatusTo, os.StatusChange_Date`).

I need to know because I am concerned the final os.statusto does not match the p.status.

Thanks in advance!

Steve

Comment: Which version of Sql Server is that?

Comment: You're right to be concerned about them not matching, this is a violation of normalization practices.  You may have a better time with a more 'traditional' history table (doesn't have to store just the status), where you just list what it was _previously_ (along with the change timestamp, obviously).

Answer (score 0):

you can join on to a sub query which gets the most recent order status

e.g.

```
SELECT p.Order_Number, p.Status, p.Order_Date, os.StatusTo, os.StatusChange_Date
FROM ORDER p
LEFT  JOIN (
          SELECT StatusTo,  Order_ID, MAX(StatusChange_Date) as StatusChange_Date
          FROM Order_Status
          GROUP BY StatusTo,    Order_ID
        )  os ON os.Order_ID= p.Order_ID
```

Comment: This will not work because derived table must first get last date per Order_ID and then join back to Order_Status to retrieve StatusTo from this row, and then it can proceed to orders. This way derived table will return a row for each Status in Order_Status for Order_ID.

Comment: (Sorry for the formatting) Could I not do something like this: 'SELECT p.Order_Number, p.Status, p.Order_Date, os.StatusTo, os.StatusChange_Date
FROM ORDER p
LEFT  JOIN (
          SELECT TOP 1 StatusTo,  Order_ID, MAX(StatusChange_Date) as StatusChange_Date
          FROM Order_Status
          ORDER BY StatusDateChange desc
        )  os ON os.Order_ID= p.Order_ID '

Comment: @Stephen.Britz - No, because (unless the syntax works extremely differently than I expect) the `TOP 1` will return exactly 1 row... the most recent of _all_ changes, not per-order.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work.  Assuming that you only care about those orders that have changes, and where the change is different than what is recorded (should be trivial to modify).

```
WITH Most_Recent_Change (order_id, statusTo, changedAt, rownum) as 
     (SELECT order_id, statusTo, statusChange_date, 
             ROWNUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY order_id
                              ORDER BY statusChange_date DESC)
      FROM Order_Status)
SELECT Order.order_number, Order.status, Order.order_date, 
       Most_Recent_Change.statusTo, Most_Recent_Change.changedAt
FROM Order
JOIN Most_Recent_Change 
ON Most_Recent_Change.order_id = Order.id
AND Most_Recent_Change.rownum = 1
AND Most_Recent_Change.statusTo <> Order.status
```

(would have an SQLFiddle example, but it's acting weird at the moment)

Please note you should be careful of the commit level you run this at, as otherwise you may get false positives from rows being concurrently updated.

Other notes:

- Don't use reserved words (like `ORDER`) for identifiers.  It's just a hassle in general
- Don't suffix columns with their datatypes, especially if those types may change in the future.  I'm aware that `order_date` isn't being *strictly* named in this fashion, but it's dangerously close.  It should probably be something like `orderedOn` (if of a strict 'solar day' type) or the better `orderedAt` (timestamp, in UTC or with timezone).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this.  Also, my "partners" did the naming convention,  Not something I would have done (but then I've been known to name stuff weird anyway.)

Comment: SQL Server does not like the OVER(ORDER...) part of this query. - Steve

Comment: @Stephen.Britz - Sorry, I seem to have had the order (heh) of the `PARTITION` and `ORDER BY` clauses swapped.